# Accessing a map's value which is a vector pair C++

Tags: c++

I have a map declared by

```
map <string, vector<pair<int, string>>>;
```

As I iterate through the map I want to access the data in the vector to print out and do operations on, I've been trying to use `myMap.at(string1).first` to access the integer associated with the key `string1`, but I keep getting type errors. Could someone explain the best way to access the data in this vector pair from its key?

Comment: When you use `myMap.at(string1)` you get a `vector` not a `pair` - because you put *vectors* in your map (not *pairs*).

Comment: What you get from `myMap[someString]` is not an integer. It's a vector of pairs. What are you *really* trying to do? And can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us (and include the actual error you get, complete and in full).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
map <string, vector<pair<int, string>>> myMap;
```

the:

```
myMap.at(string1).first
```

obviously should not compile. `myMap.at()`, if successfully matched with an associated value, will give you a `vector`. You are trying to use `.first` on that `vector`. `vector`s do not have `.first` and such members. Maybe you instead want:

```
map <string, pair<int, string>> myMap;
```

If you are sure that you want your original data type, accessing the first pair associated with `string1` would be:

```
myMap.at(string1).at(0).first
```

This will fetch a `vector<pair<int, string>>` associated with `string1` and give you the *first element* in the *first pair* of that vector.

Comment: Thanks, the at(0) was what I was missing

Comment: No problem. Consider accepting this answer by clicking the tick button underneath the votes, so the future visitors of this question will know that this answer indeed solved your problem